# Why when i run the spring boot project in STS ,"there is no resource that can be added or removed from server in STS"

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-boot

Its a Spring boot project which i have deployed in STS IDE when i am trying to run the web app in spring boot it doesn't run and shows a popup message that server resource not found.

Comment: More details, please.

Comment: Open the `Application.class` file (which has main method) and run as `Java Applicatopn` or `SpringBoot Application`. You need to create `war` file to run it in server, if thats what you are asking...